# Which is the suitable database for storing a large JSON?

Tags: json, database, storing-information

I have *only one* large JSON file. For example,

```
{   
    "Name": "Motor_M23",
    "AASID": {
        "IDType": "URI",
        "IDSpec": "http://acplt.org/AAS/Motor_M23"
    },
    "AssetID": {
        "IDType": "URI",
        "IDSpec": "http://acplt.org/Assets/Motor_M23"
    },
    "Header": {
        "PropertyValueStatementContainers": [
            {
                "Name": "Config",
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        .
```

I need to support operations following operations:

1. Querying for an element should return all child elements e.g. Querying for `AssetID` should return

   ```
   "AssetID": {
       "IDType": "URI",
       "IDSpec": "http://acplt.org/Assets/Motor_M23"
   }
   ```
2. Update value of elements.
3. Delete elements.
4. Move elements between hierarchy levels e.g. make `AssetID` child element of `AASID`.

I considered following approaches:

1. **Graph database** : I started reading about Neo4J. However, it can not create graph from JSON *intellgently*. One has to specify node type and their hierarchy order.
2. **ElasticSearch** : It can work by treating JSON as text and hence not efficient solution.
3. **Postgres** : It supports querying over JSON objects but updating, deletions won't be efficient.

Is there any good database out there which can load data from large JSON and handle my operations?

Comment: Document oriented nosql databases. Checkout [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/), it's one of the most populars and it has a lot of good documentation.

Comment: @Noki I checked out Model Trees with Nested Sets. Does MongoDB support Tree creation _automatically_ by just providing JSON? I couldn't find any way to do that.

Comment: I used mongoDB with a java application using an ODM which provided the automatic creation. I do not really know if you can do it automatically, but I am pretty sure there are scripts out there that can do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical architectural question to choose the right database, wherein you have to consider quite a few important aspects such as HA, resiliency, replication, sharding, tools support, maturity, licensing, backup & restore etc.

MongoDB and Couchbase DB are the two most popular and widely used document databases. There is no straight-forward answer to choose one, as you have to do trade-off analysis. I can share my two cents, hopefully this would help you in arriving at the right decision.

Either MongoDB or Couchbase NoSQL document databases can be considered, as json is the first class citizen in both and you get really good options to perform operations using fields.

1. MongoDB (CP support out of CAP) prefers consistency over availability whereas couchbase (AP out of CAP) is high available database.
2. MongoDB cluster works with master/slave architecture whereas couchbase cluster works with peer-to-peer distribution architecture.

There are many more dimensions to be considered and following links would take you in right direction.

https://suyati.com/blog/mongodb-vs-couchbase/

https://www.couchbase.com/comparing-couchbase-vs-mongodb

Since, in your particular case you have highlighted that you have only one large file, IMDG (in-memory data grid such as [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/)) based solutions can also be considered with a *single node* set up.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only working with JSON then you should really use a [document oriented database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) as it will save you having to wrestle something sql related.

[MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) is a good choice, supports [many drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/) and can deal with [tree structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/) (Though I'm not sure about the automatic creation)

[CRUD](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/index.html) operations are simple and cover a wide range of cases.

For very large datasets on busy servers you should use the [XFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS) file system and the [WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/) storage engine as there are some gains in performance.

It's well supported, and isn't that much of a learning curve. (I came from Pure SQL without too much trouble)

You also have the option of [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/json-mariadb-102) or [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) which also both support JSON though I have no experience with either, and in the case of MySQL I feel it was just a 'bolt on' which had to be added in the face of an up-coming requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase’ SQL-like N1QL does deep JSON traversal and manipulation.  It can also index nested array elements and UNNEST arrays at query time.  It will do what you are asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can programmatically parse and save data in SQL tables depending on operation logic you need:

1. Keep all children (with all contents) as text in 1 table, per top element.

> Element | Children (text)

```
"AssetID" |  {
        "IDType": "URI",
        "IDSpec": "http://acplt.org/Assets/Motor_M23"
    },
```

2. Keep elements in a table, and first level of children (with all contents) separately per top element.

> ID | Element
>
> Element ID | Child (text)

```
1 | "AssetID"

1 | "IDType": "URI"
1 | "IDSpec": "http://acplt.org/Assets/Motor_M23"
```

3. Keep elements (names) in a table, id and parent id to parse on unlimited levels, value if no children. This way you can query all elements (at any level) and content, update as necessary. You can also parse from any element based on ids and parent ids.

> ID | Element | Parent | Value

```
1  | "Name"   | 0 | "Motor_M23"
2  | "AASID"  | 0 | - 
3  | "IDType" | 2 | "URI",
4  | "IDSpec" | 2 | "http://acplt.org/AAS/Motor_M23"
5  | "AssetID"| 0 | -
6  | "IDType" | 5 | "URI",
7  | "IDSpec" | 5 | "http://acplt.org/Assets/Motor_M23"
8  | "Header" | 0 | -
9  | "PropertyValueStatementContainers" | 8 | -
10 | "Name"   | 9 | "Config"
```